# Limit concept query

Tags: limits

I am having trouble grasping a concept.

Is "$\lim$ x tends to a of $\ f(x)$"
different from
"$f\left( \lim_{x \to a} x \right)$"?

Like lim x tends 0 floor(x). Answer to this is obviously limit does not exist.

But floor( lim x tends to 0  x) is 0.

Isn't LHL here 0- and RHL = 0+? Then why should it behave differently?
My understanding till now was lim is just an expression which tells value of x is close to a, irrespective how and where I write it.

Comment: The [correct wording](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Limit_(mathematics)) is: "the limit of *function* $f(x)$ when $x$ tends (approaches) to $a$".

Comment: I began to edit some of the formatting here, but you might want to have a look at https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference to see how to use LaTeX here.

Comment: $f( \lim_{x \to a} x )$ does not make sense, $\lim_{x \to a} f(x)$ does.

Comment: @Dominique I disagree, expressions of type $f(\lim_{x\to a}g(x))$ are perfectly sensible. $\lim_{x\to a}g(x)$ would be some real number and we're just evaluating a function at that real number.

Comment: When you regard $\lim_{x \to a} x)$ as aa form of $\lim_{x \to a} g(x))$, then it can make sense, but then you can easily write this as $a$, without even needing the $\lim$ notation.

Answer (score 1):

$\lim_{x\to a}f(x)$ is usually different from $f(\lim_{x\to a}x)=f(a)$. You're discovering ideas around *continuity*. In your observation that $\lim_{x\to0}\lfloor x\rfloor$ does not exist, you've in particular spotted that the floor function is not continuous everywhere. In observing that $\lim_{x\to0^+}\lfloor x\rfloor=0=\lfloor0\rfloor$, you've observed that the floor function is *right continuous* (at zero) but $\lim_{x\to0^-}\lfloor x\rfloor=-1\neq0=\lfloor0\rfloor$ tells you that the floor is *not left continuous*.

The problem is that if $x$ is very close to $a$, we don't necessarily have that $f(x)$ is very close to $f(a)$; $f$ might not play nice with the ideas of 'nearness'. So $\lim_{x\to a}f(x)$ tells you what the *values* of $f$ approach (if anything) but there's no guarantee that this equals $f(a)$ in general. Think about the example $a=0$, $f(x)=\begin{cases}1&x\neq0\\-1&x=0\end{cases}$. For values of $x$ close to $a=0$, $f(x)$ is *not* close to $f(a)$. Maybe this makes more sense: $\lim_{x\to a}f(x)$ is about convergence in the 'output space' and $f(\lim_{x\to a}x)$ is about convergence in the 'input space' (and then applies $f$) and if $f$ does not have a good control over how far apart its values are, these two limits could be different since applying $f$ might ruin the convergence.

If $\lim_{x\to a}f(x)=f(a)$ for all $a\in\Bbb R$, we say $f$ is a continuous function.